# Law of Sines Non-Euclidean geometry

Tags: trigonometry, differential-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

Is the following Law of Sines valid on all surfaces isometric to a sphere?

$$\frac{\sin A }{ \sin a }= \cdots = \frac{ \sin C }{ \sin c } = E.$$

And similarly,

Is the following Law of hyperbolic Sines valid on all surfaces isometric to a pseudo-sphere?

$$\frac{\sin A }{ \sinh a }= \cdots = \frac{ \sin C }{ \sinh c} = H.$$

If so, what is this non-dimensional quantity ( $E$ or $H$ ) remaining invariant in isometric mappings that we can geometrically identify ?

The basis of this question is conservation of geodesic curvature (one among first fundamental form dependents) on constant Gauss curvature surfaces (here zero for a geodesic).

Narasimham GL

Comment: the $E$ and $H$ are wrong, delete those

Comment: @ Will Jagy.  In Euclidean geometry for a triangle the constant is 1/ circum-diameter. E and H depend on A,B and C . I wish to see it as a geometric object rather than a trigonometric expression, and failure to do so appears to me as a huge limitatation in non-Euclidean geometry.

Comment: sorry to hear that

Comment: Non-Euclidean geometry is also sorry to hear that.